# Точка пересечения прямых

Tags: c, алгоритм, геометрия

2 прямые заданы 4 точками, известно, что они пересекаются, найти точку пересечения!
не проходит один тест, выручайте! Не могу понять, где ошибка? Уже битый час пересмотрел все и в литературе, то же самое пишут...

```
int det( int a1, int a2, int b1, int b2 )
{
    return a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;   
} 

void input ( int &a, int &b, int &c )
{
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    std::cin >> x0 >> y0 >> x1 >> y1;
    a = y1 - y0;
    b = x0 - x1;
    c = -((x1 - x0) * y0 - (y1 - y0) * x0);      
}

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    input( a1, b1, c1 );
    input( a2, b2, c2 );

    d  = det( a1, b1, a2, b2 );
    d1 = det( c1, b1, c2, b2 );
    d2 = det( a1, c1, a2, c2 );

    printf("1 %.10lf %.10lf", (double) d1 / d, (double) d2 / d);

    return 0;   
}
```

---

```
проблема заключалась у тестирующей системы, у них в тесте была ошибка с точностью, вот и не проходила программа, видимо где то терялась тысячную часть ответа...! всем спасибо за помощь
```

думаю , что вопрос можно закрыть...

Comment: А если прямые параллельны? Определитель вроде должен равняться нулю, делить на него -- получается бесконечность...

Comment: Всё вроде правильно, какой тест не проходит?

Comment: есть только алгоритм пересечения двух отрезков, причем на javascript. Но, думаю, принцип одинаков: http://pastebin.com/BCQFh2tY

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection вот вам хорошая, годная статья с условием параллельности вдобавок

Comment: аlexlz, известно, что они пересекаются...)) не знаю какой тест, в том то и проблема, знал бы, исправил уже...!

Comment: Подождите, а в чём тогда вопрос? "Сделайте так, чтобы проходило тест, а какой, я вам не скажу."

Comment: тут проблема в том, что код не рабочий, я не могу понять где ошибка..

Comment: Почему не рабочий? Работает. ideone.com/NtpADg

Comment: А если проваленный тест несколько шире? Вместо чисел, например, вводятся буквы?

Или на самом деле, в задаче сказано "они пересекаются", но это еще не значит, что они на самом деле пересекаются...

К тому же "пересекаются" - а если прямые совпадают - это можно считать "пересечением"?

Ведь по сути это тоже тесты.

Comment: там все эти условия в задаче есть, и для каждого из них нужно выводить соответствующий ответ, но в данном случае я просто упростил задачу, чтобы вас не путать разными условиями а сосредоточить на конкретном вопросе!